# Accepting multiple inputs from one textbox in angular

Tags: angular

I am stuck when trying to accept input as an array in angular
here is my code

```html
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valuesArray">

 <button (click)="PerformAction()" > find</button>
```

```js
 valuesArray=[];

 PerformAction(){
    var results =this.valuesArray[0]-this.valuesArray[1]
    console.log(results);
 }
```

I get nothing at the console. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight answer is that you can not take multiple values from a input field of type number and bind it to a property of type array.

Of course, there are multiple ways to achieve same thing. And, one of the easiest way is to make input type text and input multiple values separated by ' '(space) then make the array of integers in component later when you want to use it.

Here is the template,

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="valuesString">
<br/>
<button (click)="PerformAction()" > find</button>
```

Component,

```
export class AppComponent {
  valuesString: string;
  valuesArray = [];

  PerformAction() {
    var valuesStr = this.valuesString.split(" "); //split based on ' ' and store on a variable
    this.valuesArray = valuesStr.map(x => parseInt(x)); //convert each item to int

    //perform your computation
    var results = this.valuesArray[0] - this.valuesArray[1];
    console.log(results);
  }
}
```

Note: you may want to handle char input in addition to above approach.

Also, you can do similar thing by creating custom directive, which I personally consider much cleaner approach.